# Css class definiing multiple fonts inside the same style

Tags: css, fonts, stylesheet

In my css class, I see this style defined:

```
.x-window-dlg .ext-mb-textarea {
    font:normal 12px tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```

Now tahoma,arial and helvetica are all different fonts. So which one will be applied when  I choose this style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you list multiple font-families, the first will be selected.  The others are fallbacks, in case the first fails to load.

Comment: Is there any evidence for the statement about some browsers not supporting more than three font families? Such statements often emerge from misunderstandings and are spread as rumors.

Comment: Hmm. I probably should've done my research because I can't remember what exact issue I had with IE 7 in the past. It was a few months ago. I have removed that comment from my answer, but I've definitely had some issues with font-family declarations and IE in the past. Maybe it had something to do with using a webfont via a @font-face declaration?  Can't remember.  Will post back here if I ever figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

In some browsers some fonts are not supported.

If tahoma not supported then apply arial,

If arial not supported then helvetica apply....

Answer (score 1):

Fonts are selected in order of appearance.

So in your case Tahoma will show if exists in visitors OS, then Arial, then Helvetica etcetera

Sometimes you want to supply different similar fonts for different visitor platforms.

See this link for more info about which are the core fonts to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web

Answer (score 0):

Font selection takes place on a character by character basis, by the [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#algorithm), though browsers may have difficulties for this. So for any character in the content, the browser inspects whether Tahoma contains it, and if not, it checks Arial, etc. Naturally, if some of the fonts is missing in the user’s computer, it will be skipped in this process.